# Refresh icons for files or folders in finder using cocoa

Tags: cocoa, applescript, finder

I'm developing a cocoa application for Mac. I'm applying overlay icons on files and folders using my application. But my problem is that when I change icon for file or folder from my Application than its not reflecting it in the Finder unless I click on any file or folder in the Finder. For refreshing Finder I'm running following applescript using following code from my Application:

```
NSString *source=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"Finder\" to update POSIX file \"%@\"",itemPath];
NSAppleScript *run = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:source];
[run executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

But this code is not refreshing my Finder. Any idea how to refresh Finder to immediately reflect icon for file or folder??? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Amirinder Singh have you found any solution to overcome this problem?

Comment: @jigs actually I have completed that project and had resolved that problem. But now I don't have source code with me so don't remember what was the resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the class (folder, file, disk, item, ...) when you use a string in the Finder, **item** will work for all (folder, file, ...).

Without it, It works for some, but it is not the case for everyone

Also, "**posix file thePath**" in the Finder is more reliable with parentheses.

Try this

```
NSString *source=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"Finder\" to update item (POSIX file \"%@\")",itemPath];
```

Or without **NSApplescript** :

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] noteFileSystemChanged: itemPath];
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I tried by inserting parentheses as per your suggestion but its not working. Icons are not reflection until Finder window is clicked by the user.

Comment: Try noteFileSystemChanged: --> `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] noteFileSystemChanged: itemPath];`

Comment: I check with both the options but do not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

`@"tell application \"Finder\" to update POSIX file \"%@\""` this script working fine for me.
You can also use apple events.
Below code is written by [JWWalker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/309425/jwwalker)

```
OSStatus    SendFinderSyncEvent( const FSRef* inObjectRef )
{
    AppleEvent  theEvent = { typeNull, NULL };
    AppleEvent  replyEvent = { typeNull, NULL };
    AliasHandle itemAlias = NULL;
    const OSType    kFinderSig = 'MACS';

OSStatus    err = FSNewAliasMinimal( inObjectRef, &itemAlias );
if (err == noErr)
{
    err = AEBuildAppleEvent( kAEFinderSuite, kAESync, typeApplSignature,
        &kFinderSig, sizeof(OSType), kAutoGenerateReturnID,
        kAnyTransactionID, &theEvent, NULL, "'----':alis(@@)", itemAlias );

    if (err == noErr)
    {
        err = AESendMessage( &theEvent, &replyEvent, kAENoReply,
            kAEDefaultTimeout );

        AEDisposeDesc( &replyEvent );
        AEDisposeDesc( &theEvent );
    }

    DisposeHandle( (Handle)itemAlias );
}

    return err;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I copied code provided by you in code of my application but its giving errors for kAEFinderSuite. Can you please provide me the needed source code to use this in my application and also how to call this function in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I "refresh the Finder" when needed. Maybe it will help you ;)

```
tell application "Finder"
    tell window 1 to update items
end tell
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you please provide me the source code to run this script using my application?

Comment: Just change the first line of your source code to... NSString *source = @"tell application \"Finder\" to tell window 1 to update items".

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to 'touch' the file which updates the file modification date and thus triggers thumbnail icon refresh by the Finder.

```
NSString* path = "/Users/xx/...path_to_file"
NSString* command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"touch \"%@\"", path];
int res = system(command.UTF8String);
```